# MPDF рендер svg + base64 (узел image)

Tags: php, svg, mpdf

Есть SVG'шка. Внутри, помимо path'чей есть такое:

```
<image xlink:href="тут base64" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    </image>
```

При попытке вывести svg в pdf средствами библиотеки mpdf - отрисовывается только svg без учета внутреннего узла . Как сделать так, чтобы svg отрисовалась полноценно ?

Сама svg через браузер выглядит замечательно. Либо подскажите, пожалуйта, аналогичные библиотеки. Также интересен способ конвертации в jpg/png т.к. с той же imagick не выходит

Comment: может быть вот так `style="display: block; width:100%;height:100%"`

Comment: @MonkeyMutant эту проблему решил, поставив tcpdf, вместо mpdf. Осталась проблема, как конвертировать svg в png (imagick не хочет адекватно конвертировать). В SVG есть слои и стили смешивания (mix blend mode), которые в PDF не работают.. и это печалит. Может я не правильно конвертирую через imagick, конечно..но пробовал по всем примерам, которые только мог найти.. Хотя онлайн сервисы по конвертации кушают svg и легко конвертируют в png с сохранением всех слоев и blend'ов

Comment: А если этот SVG запихнуть в canvas и от туда уже сохранять?